# api imgur cannot favorite image

Tags: javascript, api, authorization, imgur

Before asking my question , i try several method, google it my issue and decided to post here my problem.

I use imgur api 3 with javascript, i have a function to make favorite an image but without success.
Here some sample of what i did

with my client id:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/'+ currentId +'/favorite',
        //headers:{
        //    'Authorization':'Client-ID Client-id'
        //},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },error:function(error,a,b){
            console.log(error,a,b);
        }
    });
```

Result : permission denied, 403

with my access_token:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/'+ currentId +'/favorite',
        headers:{
            'Authorization ': 'Bearer '+params.access_token
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },error:function(error,a,b){
            console.log(error,a,b);
        }
    });
```

Result : "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Authorization ' is not a valid HTTP header field name."

And without the headers i have : "Authentication required", 401

[here the link for favorite an image](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-favorite)

Thanks in advance for your help.